# Probability of Finding an Empty Chair

Tags: probability

A similar question here: [Probability of finding empty seats](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542109/probability-of-finding-empty-seats)

If I have a table with ten seats, seven being taken, what is the likelihood that when I arrive, there will be an available grouping of two seats? 
How would I start this? I considered the ways to distribute two seat pairings, and I got 28 for that, then I considered all ways to distribute the 3 chairs in between seven, and got 168, yielding a pleasing 1/6, but I don't think this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the table is circular.

There are ${10\choose3}=120$ ways of having three empty seats left, assumed all equally probable. 10 ways have these three seats in a row, and $10\cdot 6$ ways have a pair of empty seats and a single empty seat. All other distributions of the three empty seats are not helpful. It follows that the probability we are looking for is ${7\over12}$.

Answer (score 0):

A=number of ways to choose 7 chairs so that there is an available grouping of 2 adjacent chairs.

B=number of ways to choose 7 chairs.

Answer should be A/B.

B=10C7=120

Now we can select a group of 2 adjacent chairs in 9 ways(c1-c2 or c2-c3, c9-c10 etc).

Thinking them as a single chair we now need to choose 7 chairs from 8 remaining chairs.

so A=9*8C7=72

answer=72/120=3/5.

Answer (score 0):

If 7 seats are taken, then 3 are empty and therefore the number of ways of arranging them are 10!/(7!.3!) which works out to 120. Now consider the 7 full seats (7F), and the empty ones as one double seater and one single empty chairs. Now the number of ways of arranging this are 9!/(7!.1!.1!) which works out to 72. So in 72 of the 120 ways of arrangement, there would be a double seater.
So probablity of finding a double seater = probablity of 2 empty seats together=72/120 which works out to 3/5 or 0.6

Answer (score 0):

There seem to some unspoken assumptions: (i) are the seats arranged in a line? If they are in a circle (so that seat 10 is next to seat 1) this is of course increases the probability. And (ii), do you need a strict two-seat, or is it ok if the third person joins your loveseat? :)

For *lined-up chairs where both 2- and 3-seats are ok*, the previous answers are correct

$$\mathrm{P\textrm{[2-seat|line]}} = \frac{\textrm{# 3 empty seat combinations with 2 adjacent}}{\textrm{# 3 empty seat combinations}} = \frac{{9\choose 1}\cdot{8\choose 1} }{10\choose 3} = \frac{3}{5},$$

where $9\choose 1$ is the number of combinations to place one 2-seat (9 positions) and $8\choose 1$ is the number of combinations to place the last seat. If however they are seated in a *ring*, there are not 9, but 10 positions for the 2-seat, and not 8 but 9 for the other seat

$$\mathrm{P\textrm{[2-seat|ring]}} = \frac{{10\choose 1}\cdot{9\choose 1}}{10\choose 3} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Finally if the last seat must be elsewhere it changes the combinations to choose for this seat, in the example of the ring, there are not 9 but 7 places to choose from, so that

$$\mathrm{P\textrm{[strict 2-seat|ring]}} = \frac{{10\choose 1}\cdot{7\choose 1} }{10\choose 3} = \frac{7}{12}$$